# Stuck in a loop when attempting to evaulate a number repeatedly

Tags: java, loops

My Goal: To make a program that can check if the number you guessed is correct. It will tell you if it's too high/low. It needs to continue giving you chances until you guess correctly. Also, it needs to be able to resume from the start after you finish if you want to.

Problem: My if statements are stuck in an infinite loop, and attempting to restart the program at the end does not work at all.

```
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class driver {
        public static void main (String [] args) {
            // Output number of guesses.

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();

            int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100) + 1;

            System.out.println(randomInt);

            System.out.println("Welcome to my guessing game. What is your first guess that is between 1 and 100?");
            int userInput = scan.nextInt();

            String playAgain = "Y";
            int guesses = 0;

            System.out.println(randomInt);

            while (playAgain == "Y") {
                if (userInput > 0 && userInput < 100) {
                    if (userInput == randomInt){
                        guesses++;
                        System.out.println ("Right! Guesses: " + guesses);
                        playAgain = "f";
                    }
                    // Too low
                    else if (userInput < randomInt) {
                        guesses++;
                        System.out.println ("Your guess was too LOW.");
                    }
                    // Too high
                    else {
                        System.out.println ("Your guess was too HIGH.");
                        guesses++;
                    }
                }
            }
            // I want to be able to resume from the top if the user says Y.
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again?(Y/N)");
            playAgain = scan.next();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post the actual code. Or really, just an mcve. And then, explain the problem a little better, maybe what you tries to fix it and why it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last two lines should be inside your while loop, the problem is with your braces

```
     while (playAgain == "Y") {
        if (userInput > 0 && userInput < 100) {
            if (userInput == randomInt){
                guesses++;
                System.out.println ("Right! Guesses: " + guesses);
                playAgain = "f";
            }

            else if (userInput < randomInt) {
                guesses++;
                System.out.println ("Your guess was too LOW.");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println ("Your guess was too HIGH.");
                guesses++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Would you like to play again?(Y/N)");
    playAgain = scan.next();
}
```

The bottom part should look like:

```
                guesses++;
            }
        }
    System.out.println("Would you like to play again?(Y/N)");
    playAgain = scan.next();
    }
}
```

The way it was means that the condition of your `while` is never updated. I assume you want it to update after each input from the user.

Comment: That works, but it stops the program after you type in one guess. It's supposed to give you as many chances as it takes to get to the solution. Also, it doesn't restart the program if you type a Y at the end.

Comment: Dont compare strings with `==` @Alex; use `equals()`

Comment: `int userInput = scan.nextInt();` This line should also be in the while loop otherwise after you make the change @BenKnoble suggests it will just ask if you want to play over and over.

Comment: Good catch knells i missed that; he still needs to fix the string

Comment: Thanks to @BenKnoble and Knells. You guys helped fix my problem!